# If an iPhone is out of power will it receive msgs?

Tags: messages

I am sending a message to my son who has an iphone6s. I have done it previously with no problem. I sent him one which was marked " delivered " and about 18 hrs sent a couple which were marked " message not delivered". Could this be the result of his battery running out of charge? I have phoned him a few times and went right to the answering machine. Thank You to anyone that can shed any light on this question Thanks  Nick, btw I am sending the msg from an iphone6.     Thanks Again.    Nick

Comment: You wouldn't get a "message not delivered" error due to his phone being off, since the message is still going to his account (no different from how you can send an email regardless if the recipient's computer is on or off).

Answer (score 1):

The device is in a state that cannot receive messages, so probably off. The messages are still going to the iMessage account/phone number because they are still active, despite the device being inactive.

Comment: I'll add that a phone having no service counts too. Like if you are in Plane Mode, under a tunnel, in a plane, etc. Just no network.

Answer (score -1):

You receive the messages when your phone is recharged

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.